# how to set setLayoutParams for an item_layout?

Tags: android

How to set  LayoutParams() for my items_layout for all screen size. in MainActivity.java to resize the activity according the datas i receive to refull a listview I wrote the following code for set Layout params

```
PercentRelativeLayout oidit;
 oidit = (PercentRelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idit);o
idit.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

this code work fine in a normal screen  1080 dp or lower , but when i run that code in a higher screen like 1440 dp or a tablet screen , can't see all datas cause getLayoutParams().height = 100; is too small 
i would like to know how can i reset the items_layout size for all resolution screen.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Use Relative + Linear layout combination in your project. Read the Doc provide by Android Developers